# How to replace all instances of one hex code with another in CSS?

Tags: css, wordpress

**DISCLAIMER:** I am very new to html editing and I am learning by experience so far.

I am customizing a theme for a WordPress webpage. I would like to replace all instances of one hex color with another.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
background: #308F6F;
color: #fff;
text-shadow: none;
```

I would like to replace every single instance of `#308F6F` with another hex color (`#ffcc00`).

Is there a short-key to find and replace text? I know command+F (mac), but I'm not aware of anything that will help me replace the text. Or, if there is a code I can insert that would override all instances of one text for another?

I am editing this in the Wordpress CSS Editor.

Thanks!

Comment: It might be best if you actually used a code editor (eg. Visual Studio Code) for this. In VSC you can hit cmd+h and it'll let you find and replace all of the instances of any given string. Of course, for that you'll need to download the stylesheet to your computer, do the changes there, and then reupload the stylesheet to the server.

Comment: I have the style sheet for this theme. Is it as simple as copy+paste the text of the style sheet in Worpress and paste into VSC? Thanks for your response! Again, forgive me as Im still very new to this.

Comment: Yep, you can do that as well. Why didn't I think of that? Haha